# How to add a timer in HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to to add a timer for a Snake Game and to start it simultaneously when the game starts and to stop it when it's finished. Any help please? Many thanks!

Comment: Please just dont copy/paste your code and ask for help. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Amil. My apologies but I am really new on js and html5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below (just sample code) it will count 5 secs and then alert the total seconds. You need to make the math to get hours, minutes, seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var secs = 0;
var id = setInterval(function(){ 
    secs++; console.log(secs);
  if(secs> 5){
    clearInterval(id);
    alert('Total Time: ' + secs + ' seconds');
   }
}, 1000);
});
```

Then you can put the logic inside a start/stop method or wherever you need to place it.

With pure Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
var secs = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function(){ 
        secs++; console.log(secs);
      if(secs> 5){
        clearInterval(id);
        alert('Total Time: ' + secs + ' seconds');
       }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Hi Manuel. Thanks for the help, however, I have to implement in JS and JQuery is not allowed. Thanks

Comment: Frank, jQuery in my example is used to be sure the elements are loaded with the `$(document).ready(function(){`. You can replace that line (the first one) with `window.onload = function() {` to use pure javascript. Also remove the last `)` so it does not have a syntax issue. (updated above) Hope that helps!

Comment: Why is it inside a DOM ready? What DOM does it rely on?

Comment: Alex, yes. Because I don't know where or at which point should trigger, then I just made an example preventing any load issues. It doesn't mean that it should wait for the ready of course.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

```js
function changeValue() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ++value;
}

var timerInterval = null;
function start() {
  stop(); // stoping the previous counting (if any)
  value = 0;
  timerInterval = setInterval(changeValue, 1000);  
}
var stop = function() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
```

```html
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<button onclick="start()">Start time</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop time</button>
```

Comment: Hi Mate. Many thanks for the help. It really works, however, would be possible to the counter start automatically when I press the game's Start button? Thank You.

Comment: As you can see I'm already starting automatically after the button is pressed. `<button onclick="start()">Start time</button>`

Comment: I think you should read some basic stuff about JavaScript and HTML events. Probably a game is too much as a starting point.